Not eligible for offer IAP
I am working on the In app purchase adding promotional offer in my application. I set up the promotional offer in App store connect successfully.
I created the signature from the backend and it returned signature, nonce and timestamp. After that I initialized the SKPaymentDiscount method but it gives me an error "This offer is available only to current or previous subscribers of this app.\n\n[Environment: Xcode]". I am following the apple documentation for reference.
Apple documentation IAP
// PrepareForOffer
  func prepareOffer(usernameHash: String, productIdentifier: String, offerIdentifier: String, completion: @escaping (SKPaymentDiscount) -> Void) {

        let applicationUserName = UUID().uuidString.lowercased()
        let param:[String:Any] = ["productIdentifier": productIdentifier,
                                  "applicationUsername": applicationUserName,
                                  "offerID": offerIdentifier]
        param.printJson()
        APIManager.sharedInstance.usersAPIManager.GetSignatureData(params: param, success: { (responseObject) in
            self.purchase = Mapper<IAPModel>().map(JSON: responseObject as [String: Any])
            
            // Create offer
            var uuid = UUID(uuidString: self.purchase?.nonce ?? "")
            let discountOffer = SKPaymentDiscount(identifier: offerIdentifier, keyIdentifier: "5WWL777LG5", nonce: uuid ?? UUID(), signature: self.purchase?.signature ?? "", timestamp: (self.purchase?.timestamp ?? 0) as NSNumber)

            // Pass offer in completion block
            completion(discountOffer)
        }) { (error) in
            print(error)
        }
      }

// BuyProduct
  func buyProduct(product: SKProduct, forApplicationUsername usernameHash: String, withOffer offer: SKPaymentDiscount) {

        print("buyProduct", offer.debugDescription.description)
      // Create payment object
      let payment = SKMutablePayment(product: product)

      // Apply username and offer to the payment
      payment.applicationUsername = usernameHash
      payment.paymentDiscount = offer

      // Add payment to paymentQueue
      InAppPurchaseManager.shared.paymentQueue.add(payment)
    }


Can anyone help me on this?
